# Access other adwords accounts without user authentication every time?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm writing an app that needs to periodically get reports and update campaigns for a few users. The app can access their accounts now when they login and authorize, but what I want/need is for oauth to give access to the app to access their accounts whenever the script has to run. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The relevant documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline).

You need to add `access_type=offline` to your request for an authorization code. The user will then be prompted to grant offline access to your script in the consent screen, and once he accepts, the response to your app will include a refresh token. Refresh tokens don't expire and can be used to generate new access tokens.

Note that if you lose a refresh token, you'll need to request authorization from your use again, this can be done by including `prompt=consent` in the request.